# Google Apps Email Audit API: POST запрос для создания монитора за почтовым ящиком пользователя

Tags: email, google-app-engine

С помощью **Google Apps Email Audit API** пытаюсь создать монитор, который будет дублировать все письма пользователя **rabbit@mydomain.com** в почтовый ящик **auditor@mydomain.com**
В ответ получаю сообщение об ошибке: "Content is not allowed in prolog."

```
 $url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/monitor/mydomain.com/rabbit';

 $txtXML  = "<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>";
 $txtXML .= "<apps:property name='destUserName' value='auditor'/>";
 $txtXML .= "<apps:property name='endDate' value='2015-12-31 00:00'/>";
 $txtXML .= "</atom:entry>";

 $post_data = array( "xml" => $txtXML );

 $context = stream_context_create(
     array( 'http' => array(
         'method' => 'POST',
         'header'  => 'Content-length: '. strlen( $txtXML ) . PHP_EOL .
         'Content-type: application/atom+xml' . PHP_EOL . 
         'Authorization: Bearer ' . trim( $accessToken2v3 ) . PHP_EOL .
         '',
         'content' => http_build_query( $post_data )
      )
    )
 );

 $response = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
```

P.S. Подготовил параметры для POST запроса, изучив следующую документацию:

- [Google Apps Email Audit API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/);
- [Инструкция по Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth);
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Запрос отлично работает в [песочнице](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). [Input your own scopes](https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/).

Comment: похоже на [проблему иксигрек](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576): дублирование писем логичнее осуществлять средствами smtp-сервера.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за идею!
Но мне хотелось бы научиться работать как с этим, так и с другими API Google. То есть, для меня важно понять как правильно отправлять POST запросы.